# How to get Auth::id() server-side on ajax post? It's returning null. Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

My user is authenticated.

To prove it:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
```

...and the user info is logged to console as expected.

So experts, please tell me, how can I get `Auth::id()` on the server side on an ajax post??

`Auth::id()` returns `null`.  It doesn't make sense that I would pass the user id with the data payload when the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every route going through `api`, by default you need to do

```
$id = Auth::guard('api')->id; //OR 

$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
if ( $user ) $id = $user->id;
```

You could do it in one line

```
$id = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
```

But if the user fails, you will receive `Cannot get property id of null`